# openssh slower in windows 7 than linux

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ssh, cygwin, putty

I can acces to a ssh server. My client ssh is on a dual-boot machine: windows 7 and ubuntu 14.10

With ubuntu, I can download at the speed of 190 ko/s in average (my connection is 2 Mb). Even better, with the hpn-ssh patch, my download speed is about 230ko/s

Unfortunately, with windows 7 and putty (or openssh in cygwin), my download speed is about 90ko/s.

Does anyone know how I can have the same speed in my wondows 7 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check to see what you have installed on your computer and running in the background, it is likely you may have something else taking up network resources. You may also have DNS configured differently on the two machines which could play a small role.

Comment: I checked that nothing is running in the background. Moreover, the dns server is the same on both systems.